# Yii2 #403 error in IE only, and also when compatibility view mode is on

Tags: php, internet-explorer, yii2, http-status-code-403

My application is developed in Yii2 running on LAMP over intranet only.
Strange issue is Project URL opens fine in Chrome with below URL entered and redirected to login URL below.

http://localhost/portal/
redirects to 
http://localhost/portal/frontend/web/index.php/site/login

Even this work fine with IE compatibility view mode off.

But when compatibility view is on, it redirects to below URL and gives #403 authentication error.

http://localhost/portal/frontend/web/index.php/

If any one can help me with Yii application page life cycle / compile sequence and provide solution to above issue would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: localhost by default maps to the Internet zone. IE has restrictions preventing navigation/redirects into a zone of lower integrity. File>Properties tells you which IE security zone a domain maps to. F12>Networking tab, click 'Start' button the test your page... will tell you the server response codes for the redirect type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to ignore IE compatibility view settings by adding the following meta tag in your main.php

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```